# Is there a way to determine length of a base64 encoded value without knowing the encoding of decoded value?

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, base64

I have a base 64 encoded value and I would like to know the lenght of the decoded value by using the this value without knowing the encoding of the decoded value.

For example, base 64 encoded value of **"foo"** is **Zm9v**. When I decode it like this:

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("Zm9v");
```

I get an array which has three bytes. In this case I can easily determine the lenght as 3, but let's say we have **"ü"** as the value which is **"w7w="** in base 64:

```
// length = 2
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("w7w=");
```

The length of the byte array is `2`, so the first solution failed, the other option I think of is to get string from the bytes using `UTF8` encoding and then get the length:

```
var lenght = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes).Lenght;
```

I think this would work as `UTF8` is commonly used but again I'm not comfortable with this solution either. How should I go about this? Is it impossible to find a general solution to this without knowing the encoding of the value in the first place?

Comment: But you are essentially asking if you  can decode arbitrary byte array without knowing the encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not know the length of the string from the byte array if you don't have the encoding. A 1000 byte BLOB might be a 500 char Unicode or a 1000 char ASCII string. Without Encoding you'll never know.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here, one which is easy and one which is (in the general case) impossible.

The easy one is to get the number of bytes encoded by a base64 string. You can do this without actually performing the decode by looking at the number of characters in the base64 string, and also how many `=` characters there are at the end.

The in-general-impossible one is to get the number of characters encoded by an arbitrary sequence of bytes. I say in-general-impossible, because *the number of characters depends on the encoding, and correctly **guessing** the encoding, always, is impossible*. This problem is sometimes known as [the Notepad file encoding problem](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070417-00/?p=27223), and Raymond Chen explains it there far better than I can, although I will excerpt:

> For example, consider this file:
>
> ```
> D0 AE
> ```
>
> Depending on which encoding you assume, you get very different
>   results.
>
> - If you assume 8-bit ANSI (with code page 1252), then the file consists of the two characters U+00D0 U+00AE, or "Ð®". Sure this looks
>     strange, but maybe it's part of the word VATNIÐ® which might be the
>     name of an Icelandic hotel.
> - If you assume UTF-8, then the file consists of the single Cyrillic character U+042E, or "Ю".
> - If you assume Unicode big-endian, then the file consists of the Korean Hangul syllable U+D0AE, or "킮".
> - If you assume Unicode little-endian, then the file consists of the Korean Hangul syllable U+AED0, or "껐".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the length of bytes, convert it to string and then get the length of the string:

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("w7w=");
int length = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes).Length;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9Hw8Ut)

Comment: I mentioned this in the question, but I don't think this would work correctly if the value contains a character that can't be represented in UTF8.

Comment: @SelmanGenç bey, I don't think so, would you give an example?

Comment: @SelmanGenç "character that can't be represented in UTF8" might be a terminology problem. UTF-8 can encode any Unicode character. I think you are saying that the bytes resulting from a UTF-8 encoding can never be arbitrary sequences of arbitrary values 0-255. So, if you take some  sequence of bytes, it might fail to decode as UTF-8. (Of course, you'd have a bigger problem if they didn't fail to decode as UTF-8 but they weren't encoded as UTF-8 in the first place.)